# Efficiently extract WikiData entities from text

Tags: scala, machine-learning, information-retrieval, wikidata, wikidata-api

I have a lot of texts (millions), ranging from 100 to 4000 words. The texts are formatted as written work, with punctuation and grammar. Everything is in English.

The problem is simple: *How to extract every WikiData entity from a given text?*

An entity is defined as every *noun*, proper or regular. I.e., names of people, organizations, locations and things like *chair*, *potatoes* etc.

**So far I've tried the following:**

1. Tokenize the text with [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/manual/opennlp.html), and use the [pre-trained models](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/) to extract *people*, *location*, *organization* and regular *nouns*.
2. Apply [Porter Stemming](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/stemmer/PorterStemmer.html) where applicable.
3. Match all extracted nouns with the [wmflabs-API](https://wdq.wmflabs.org/api_documentation.html) to retrieve a potential WikiData ID.

This *works*, but I feel like I can do better. One obvious improvement would be to cache the relevant pieces of WikiData locally, which I plan on doing. However, before I do that, I want to check if there are other solutions.

Suggestions?

*I tagged the question Scala because I'm using [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) for the task.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- consider Stanford NER in comparison to OpenNLP to see how it compares on your corpus
- I wonder at the value of stemming for most entity names
- I suspect you might be losing information by dividing the task into discrete stages
- although Wikidata is new, the task isn't, so you might look at papers for Freebase|DBpedia|Wikipedia entity recognition|disambiguation

In particular, DBpedia Spotlight is one system designed for exactly this task.

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/38389.pdf
http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1057/Nebhi_LD4IE2013.pdf

Comment: Stemming is actually only done on nouns identified as non-proper and plural, which is not a majority. Thanks for the papers/pointing out dbpedia spotlight. I did not know about these.

Comment: DBpedia is actually linked to Wikidata, (for some reason I missed that), so I'll mark your answer as accepted, since I was able to use DBpedia spotlight to fetch DBpedia ID, and use Sparql+RDF to fetch the Wikidata ID's directly.

Comment: @habitats Would you mind going into more detail on how to link them? I am trying this right now, but often there is no direct link from the dbpedia entry to wikidata